# displaying an internal variable by default

Tags: powershell

I Have a PowerShell object which looks like this:

```
$MyObject = New-Object PSObject

$MyObject | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Name
$MyObject | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Json -Value $Json
```

If I will do:

```
$MyObject
```

I will see :

```
Name                         Json
----                         --------------------------
Name                         {@json-powershell format}
```

What I would like to have is that when using the `$MyObject` the default view will show me `($MyObject).Json`.

I couldn't figure out a way to do so.

Comment: What's wrong with using `$MyObject.Json` when you want `$MyObject.Json`? Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you think you need this for?

Comment: My object is a response which contains a JSON and also contains other variables. For CLI based usage, I would like that if the user call a function which directly return such an object, the user will be able to see the json parsed and not whole the properties available in the object. I have used the DefaultDisplayPropertySet functionality to keep in view only the json field but it shows it in a list instead of opening the json like doing ($MyObject).Json.

Answer (score 1):

You can override ToString() Method:

```
$MyObject | Add-Member -type ScriptMethod -Name ToString -Value
{$this.Json} -PassThru -Force
```

If you then use you variable in a string the Json is displayed.

```
"$MyObject"
```

Is that what you were looking for? Where do you want your Output to go? The Console? The debug stream?

Comment: Let me check. it may be exactly what I need !!

Comment: Well, it is kinda working if I use "$MyObject" but it is not working when doing $Myobject what I need.

Comment: I want it on console. not as an argument.

Comment: Whats wrong with using `Write-Host $MyObject`? This would display the desired result on the console. Could you give us the context of what you are doing so that we can understand the problem?

Comment: a. i doesn't show it as I needed. it show it as a json format and not parsed when doing (MyObject).Json. b. the context is that we try to provide a CLI kind of requests, and when using it as a CLI we do not want to show the answer as we asked only for the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achive is described in this post: http://learn-powershell.net/2013/08/03/quick-hits-set-the-default-property-display-in-powershell-on-custom-objects/

```
$defaultDisplaySet = 'Json'
$defaultDisplayPropertySet = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSPropertySet(‘DefaultDisplayPropertySet’,[string[]]$defaultDisplaySet)
$PSStandardMembers = [System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo[]]@($defaultDisplayPropertySet)

$object.PSObject.TypeNames.Insert(0,'User.Information')
$object | Add-Member MemberSet PSStandardMembers $PSStandardMembers

$Object
```

Comment: This is what I did at first place (I referred to it in my question). I am not quite sure why you add the TypeNames. Because I didn't do anything like that.